# How to create an Object in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and am trying understanding it. I need to create objects for the below Schema I defined. For clarification does this statement create a "Class" in OOP and the statement ***var GroupTemplate = mongoose.model('GroupTemplate',GrouptemplateSchema);*** and the code  ***var GroupTemplate = mongoose.model('GroupTemplate',GrouptemplateSchema);***create an object for the class?

My question is : When a user submits a request for a template, I need to instantiate the objects so that the user can use them. I tried looking up on google but can't find much. Can anyone explain how to do it? thanks in advance

```
var GrouptemplateSchema = new Schema({
  templateId:{type:Number,required:true,unique:true},
  maxValue:{type:Number,default:100},
  minValue:{ type:Number, default:0},
  responseTime:{type:Number},
  type:{type:Number},
  availableFrom:{type:Date,default:Date.now },
});


var Template = mongoose.model('Template',templateSchema);
var GroupTemplate = mongoose.model('GroupTemplate',GrouptemplateSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

*var GroupTemplate = mongoose.model('GroupTemplate',GrouptemplateSchema);* expression is  assign mpngoose model object to **GroupTemplate** variable. You should **export** this variable as a *module* for using from another file. like:

```
module.exports = GroupTemplate ;
```

say in model.js file you define your model and export

```
var GrouptemplateSchema = new Schema({
  templateId:{type:Number,required:true,unique:true},
  maxValue:{type:Number,default:100},
  minValue:{ type:Number, default:0},
  responseTime:{type:Number},
  type:{type:Number},
  availableFrom:{type:Date,default:Date.now },
});

var GroupTemplate = mongoose.model('GroupTemplate',GrouptemplateSchema);
module.exports = GroupTemplate ;

//or just registered as mongoose model instead of above 2 lines

//mongoose.model('GroupTemplate',GrouptemplateSchema);
```

and in your controller.js file get exported model using **require** and create new object

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GroupTemplate= require('GroupTemplate');  // get GroupTemplate model
// or if you register as mongoose model
// require('../model/model.js');
// var GroupTemplate = mongoose.model('GroupTemplate');

var newGroupTemplate = new GroupTemplate({ // create new object of GroupTemplate
    templateId:1,
    maxValue: 12,
    // rest of code
});
```